# Assign value to a text box on form based on multiple text boxex value with if condition - MS ACCESS

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Let me explain,i have fields (text boxes) on a form as below

```
textbox1 = can hold Yes or NO
textbox2 = can hold Yes or NO
textbox3 = can hold Yes or NO
textbox4 = can hold Yes or NO
```

`textboxResult` holds the Concatenated value of the labels (captions) of only those text boxes whose values  are "Yes"

I have tried many possible solutions (in my mind) including below but no  luck. Tested below code with OR operator also.

```
If Me.textbox1.Value = "Yes" And Me.textbox2.Value = "Yes" And _
               Me.textbox3.Value = "Yes" And Me.textbox4.Value = "Yes" Then
    Me.textboxResult.Value = Me.Label1.Caption & "," & 
    Me.Label2.Caption & "," & Me.Lable3.Caption & "," & 
    Me.Label4.Caption
Else
    Me.textboxResult.Value = "NA"
End If
```

I want to assign the label's caption of those textboxes whose value is YES. Please help

Comment: What `Caption` of the Textboxes are you talking about? Texboxes do not have a caption! And you mention `Labels` just once. You should get clear what the difference between `Label` and `Textbox` is and between `Value` and `Caption`! **AND** include an example expected result **AND** what does "but no luck" mean? Does it not work, does it crash, does the if-body not get reached?

Comment: Thank You luk2302 for prompt reply. i have edited the question body and code too for clear understanding. It works but not the way i want it to work. I only want to concatenate (join) those textboxes labels which caries YES value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need the concatenated value of all the TextBox labels. So one bulk `AND` might not be the option, maybe check every control. something like.

```
Dim txtResult As String

If Me.textbox1 = "Yes" Then _
    txtResult = txtResult & Me.textbox1.Controls.Item(0).Caption & ","

If Me.textbox2 = "Yes" Then _
    txtResult = txtResult & Me.textbox2.Controls.Item(0).Caption & ","

If Me.textbox3 = "Yes" Then _
    txtResult = txtResult & Me.textbox3.Controls.Item(0).Caption & ","

If Me.textbox4 = "Yes" Then _
    txtResult = txtResult & Me.textbox4.Controls.Item(0).Caption & ","

If Len(txtResult) > 0 Then
    Me.textboxResult = Left(txtResult, Len(txtResult)-1)
Else
    Me.textboxResult = "NA"
End If
```

**NOTE** - Me.TextBoxName.Controls.Item(0) will return the associated label with the `TextBoxName`. If the text box does not have an association, then you might end up with errors.

---

**EDIT** - After your edit, if you simply want to use the label's caption, just replace the `Me.textbox.Controls(0).Caption` to `Me.LableName.Caption`

Comment: that is what I would call similar solutions :D

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comment you should not do a combined if but rather 4 seperate ifs for each textBox:

```
Dim txt As String
txt = ""
If Me.textbox1.Value = "Yes" Them _
    txt = txt & Me.Label1.Caption & ", "

If Me.textbox2.Value = "Yes" Then _
    txt = txt & Me.Label2.Caption & ", "

If Me.textbox3.Value = "Yes" Then _
    txt = txt & Me.Label3.Caption & ", "

If Me.textbox4.Value = "Yes" Then _
    txt = txt & Me.Label4.Caption & ", "

If Len (txt) > 0 Then
    txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 2)
Else 
    txt = "NA"
End If

Me.textboxResult = txt
```

Comment: Absolutely or something like ***Great minds think alike*** ;)

Comment: Thank You luk2302 too, for your help and solution :)